# onReceive method not called when i removed app , and i write code in right way

Tags: java, android

i add **android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED** as action 
and this my receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED"/>
                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and my MyBroadcastReceiver here

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"app Removed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("MyBroadcastReceiver","app Removed");

    }
}
```

so i want to notify when app is removed from Device but is not working

Comment: Is this receiver in the package that is being removed?

Comment: yes must called when app removed @TKK

Comment: A receiver in a package that has been removed will obviously never be called. This event is for *other* apps to be notified when a package is removed, e.g., so a launcher can remove the icon.

Comment: oh thanks so this Receiver  is not for removed my app ,, so what action i must add to know my app is go to removed ?

Comment: You can't. [There was a hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062780/how-to-start-an-activity-or-service-before-an-app-application-is-uninstalled-by) that could do this, but it was considered a security risk and Google was reportedly working to fix it back in 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't listen to `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FULLY_REMOVED/android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED` on your all package because your own `BroadcastReceiver` is removed when your package is removed.

Comment: so no another way to do that ?